Can't Get FlatList Scrolling to Work in React Native with Expo
I'm losing my mind trying to get scrolling to work in React Native using Expo. I've gone through the entire documentation for both ScrollView and FlatList and spent a whole day debugging, but scrolling still doesn't work on either one. I'm even considering switching to another framework because of this issue.
Screenshot of scrolling working on scrcopy
I've tried everything, including asking ChatGPT for help, but nothing has worked. What makes it even more confusing is that scrolling works if I use Scrcpy on Windows and scroll with my mouse.
If anyone can fix this, I’d seriously consider offering a reward! Any help is appreciated.
Here is the snippet with the FlatList
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.searchInput}
                        placeholder="Search by model or brand..."
                        value={searchQuery}
                        onChangeText={setSearchQuery}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sortButtons}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={[styles.button, sortBy === 'price' && styles.activeButton]}
                        onPress={() => setSortBy('price')}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sort by Price</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={[styles.button, sortBy === 'distance' && styles.activeButton]}
                        onPress={() => setSortBy('distance')}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sort by Distance</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <FlatList
                    data={filteredListings}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(
item
) => item.id}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
                    initialNumToRender={10}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    windowSize={10}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>

And the styling
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    safeArea: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    headerContainer: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    searchContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#F9FAFB',
        borderRadius: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderColor: '#D0D5DD',
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    searchInput: {
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    sortButtons: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    button: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        borderRadius: 8,
        backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
        marginHorizontal: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    activeButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#007AFF',
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#333',
    },
    flatListStyle: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    listContainer: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    loadingContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    listingItem: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginBottom: 10,
        padding: 15,
        elevation: 2,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 2,
    },
    listingDetails: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    brand: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});


which device or simulator are you using for your tests? I just tried your code and it works fine. Here's a snack. Be sure to try it on android/ios simulator or real devices.

Not a simulator its on my Samsung Galaxy S21 in Expo Go. I tried the snack and it works too. seems like the problem could be in my App.ts. Thanks!

Also Screencopy or scrcpy is a opensource tool to mirror android pdevice screens on windows. It has support for audio,keyboard, gestures etc.

Can you be more specific about what isn’t working

@johnhaup Scrolling is not working on a mobile phone using finger gestures.
